# Keep right to left text (Arabic - Hebrew - Farsi) when exporting to pdf

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I can successfully display Right-To-Left text (Arabic - Hebrew - Farsi) in Matlab figures using the command `text(.)`. However, saving it into PDF, the characters are printed from Left-To-Right again.

How can I let Matlab keep it Right-to-Left when converting to PDF?

Minimal example:

```
fig = figure(1) 
set(0,'DefaultTextFontname', 'Arial') 
rectangle('position',[0,0,600,1435]);
axis equal      
text(100,1200,'الكتاب','fontname','Arial', ... 
'VerticalAlignment','middle','Horizont‌​alAlignment','left',... 
'FontSize',20,'color',[1 0 0],'Rotation',90);
print(fig,'MySavedPlot','-dpdf','-r2000)
```